# Special Command and Caption

Tags: captions

I use the following code excessivle,

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifinstr#1#2{%
  \def\@ifinstr##1#2##2\@nil{%
    \ifstrempty{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}}%
  \@ifinstr#1\@@nil#2\@nil
}

\def\popleft#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@popleft\expandafter{\@tmpa}{#1}{#2}}
\def\@popleft#1#2#3{%
  \ifinstr{#1}{|}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1\q@stop}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1|\q@stop}}
\def\@@popleft#1#2\q@nil#3|#4\q@stop{\edef#1{#4}\edef#2{#3}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\def\@assignvalues#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpb{#1}\edef\@tmpc{#2}%
  \popleft\@tmpb\currentvalueA
  \popleft\@tmpc\currentvalueB
  \csedef{\currentvalueA}{\currentvalueB}%
  \ifdefempty\@tmpb{}{\assignvalues\@tmpb\@tmpc}%
}
\makeatother
```

But this piece of code doesn't work if i use the caption command in this way...

```
\assignvalues{bcaption}{Äußere Restfeuchte}
```

....

```
\end{pspicture}
\caption[Warscheinlichkeitsverteilung~\protect\bcaption]{\space~\protect\bcaption\space (AD)}
```

The first compile works, but the second one generates an entry in the lof file the following entry will be shwon as

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.12}{\ignorespaces Wahrscheinlichkeitsplot Äu\T 1\ss ere Restfeuchte Rohstoff C}}{11}{figure.caption.18}
```

Has anybody an idea what the problem could be, for sure its a combination of the code above and the caption argument, which has to be robust. But I cannot solve the problem at the moment.

Any ideas?

Update 1: MWE (non Working more than one times)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Euro-Zeichen etc...
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}[2008/08/24]
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 

\makeatletter
\def\ifinstr#1#2{%
  \def\@ifinstr##1#2##2\@nil{%
    \ifstrempty{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}}%
  \@ifinstr#1\@@nil#2\@nil
}

\def\popleft#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@popleft\expandafter{\@tmpa}{#1}{#2}}
\def\@popleft#1#2#3{%
  \ifinstr{#1}{|}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1\q@stop}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1|\q@stop}}
\def\@@popleft#1#2\q@nil#3|#4\q@stop{\edef#1{#4}\edef#2{#3}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\def\@assignvalues#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpb{#1}\edef\@tmpc{#2}%
  \popleft\@tmpb\currentvalueA
  \popleft\@tmpc\currentvalueB
  \csedef{\currentvalueA}{\currentvalueB}%
  \ifdefempty\@tmpb{}{\assignvalues\@tmpb\@tmpc}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\blankimageX}{
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\psset{xunit=\scalex cm,yunit=\scaley cm, runit=\scaler cm}
\psCancel{\begin{pspicture}(\xstart,\ystart)(\xend,\yend)
% Achsen
% X-Achse
\psline(\xstart,\yistart)(\xend,\yistart)
% Y-Achse
\psline(\xstart,\yistart)(\xstart,\yend)
\psline(\xend,\yistart)(\xend,\yend)
\psline(\xstart,\yend)(\xend,\yend)
\end{pspicture}}
\caption[Wahrscheinlichkeitsplot \bcaption]{Wahrscheinlichkeitsplot \bcaption nach Anderson-Darling} 
    \label{\lab}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter A}
\assignvalues{scalex|scaley|scaler|xstart|xend|ystart|yend|yistart}{1|1|1|0|8|0|5|-1}
\assignvalues{bcaption|lab}{Äußere Restfeuchte|fig:picdesc}

\bcaption

\section{Section A}
\chapter{Chapter B}

\blankimageX

\section{Section B}
\end{document}
```

LG Goldnas

Comment: It's rather hard to tell by eye what that code is doing, pleas _always_ post code in the form of a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, transform the code snippet into a minimal document we can play with.

Comment: I will do the MWE, hint, I have asked at one more place in the net, see the same question @ http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=73700&page=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite hard to follow the code; but the problem is in the fact that you're using `\edef` on input such as `Äußere` which is *very* dangerous as it produces all the instructions to print the characters.

Use `\protected@edef` instead for the token lists that can contain these "high bit set" characters; `etoolbox` provides also `\protected@csedef`.

Here's the amended code with a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifinstr#1#2{%
  \def\@ifinstr##1#2##2\@nil{%
    \ifstrempty{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}}%
  \@ifinstr#1\@@nil#2\@nil
}

\def\popleft#1#2{%
  \protected@edef\@tmpa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@popleft\expandafter{\@tmpa}{#1}{#2}}
\def\@popleft#1#2#3{%
  \ifinstr{#1}{|}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1\q@stop}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1|\q@stop}}
\def\@@popleft#1#2\q@nil#3|#4\q@stop{\protected@edef#1{#4}\protected@edef#2{#3}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\def\@assignvalues#1#2{%
  \protected@edef\@tmpb{#1}\protected@edef\@tmpc{#2}%
  \popleft\@tmpb\currentvalueA
  \popleft\@tmpc\currentvalueB
  \protected@csedef{\currentvalueA}{\currentvalueB}%
  \ifdefempty\@tmpb{}{\assignvalues\@tmpb\@tmpc}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter A}
%\assignvalues{scalex|scaley|scaler|xstart|xend|ystart|yend|yistart}{1|1|1|0|8|0|5|-1}
\assignvalues{bcaption|lab}{Äußere Restfeuchte|fig:picdesc}

\begin{figure}
\caption[Wahrscheinlichkeitsplot \bcaption]{Wahrscheinlichkeitsplot \bcaption{} nach Anderson-Darling} 
    \label{\lab}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Goldnas if this solution has solved the problem, don't forget to accept it using the green check mark :)